# how to fix and create logs in C# programming with access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2007

My problem is that I cannot code logs (the one who wrote down every action you do in your program). So I am asking how can you create logs, and another thing I have this code here. I think it is for creating logs but I don't know how to edit the things that must be edited in the codes below. Can someone help me?

```
public class LogWriter
    {
        private string m_exePath = string.Empty;
        public LogWriter(string logMessage)
        {
            LogWrite(logMessage);
        }
        public void LogWrite(string logMessage)
        {
            m_exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(m_exePath + "\\" + "LOGG.txt"))
                {
                    Log(logMessage, w);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("new"+ex);
            }
        }

        public void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter txtWriter)
        {
            try
            {
                txtWriter.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
                txtWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                    DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                txtWriter.WriteLine("  :");
                txtWriter.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
                txtWriter.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("old"+ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We don't know what you want that code to do so we can't know how to edit it either. It looks like it writes log entries to a file (poorly). Are you saying you don't know how to use this class?

Comment: yes I'm really confused on how to use it, I'm new to programming so please bear with me

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into a logging framework if it is practical for you to use something other than this class you have shown. Look at Serilog or even Nlog. They are well designed for thread safety and efficiency.

To use this class, or any class (that is not static) you create an instance with `new`:

```
LogWriter logger = new LogWriter("a message here..");
```

Unfortunately this class was designed so you cannot instantiate it without writing a log entry so you will get "a message here.." log written at this point.

Now that you have an instance you can call methods on it, for instance:

```
logger.LogWrite("This is a log message...");
```

You should be able to see your log entries in the LOGG.txt file in the same folder as your program.

Don't think of this in terms of just this logger. If you had more experience programming you would already know how to do this. A little time invested in tutorials will go a long way.